# My SCNNodes are constant in size for any specified radius

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm newbie in using SceneKit and my nodes are too large for my screen (and changing the radius didn't help, see the code and the pic below).

Code: https://pastebin.com/GGikSTyY

```
let scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
// If I set size to 2, 5, 120 the answer is the same.
let hydrogenAtom = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
hydrogenAtom.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.lightGray
hydrogenAtom.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = UIColor.red
let atomsNode = SCNNode()
let carbonNode = SCNNode(geometry: hydrogenAtom)
carbonNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-6, 0, 0)
atomsNode.addChildNode(carbonNode)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(atomsNode)
sceneView.scene = scene
```

And there's this piece of code in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.frame = self.viewMain.bounds
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.viewMain.addSubview(sceneView)
}
```

Image (for whatever radius I set): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjGhJ.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not creating a camera. You're just getting a default one that is centering on the node, making it appear the same size. You'll notice changing the position of the sphere has no apparent effect either.

You can create a camera like this:

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
```